# How to center grid containing repeat(auto-fit, minmax(15rem, 1fr));

Tags: html, sass

I am finishing my portfolio site, but I encountered a problem. I used auto-fit function, because I want it to be responsive, and I will keep adding new images there each month.

I found that I can't center it the way I want, because grid is filling empty space with additional columns which I don't need right now, so my grid is kissing left side of my website. Please help guys, you are the best! :)

```
<section class="projects">
    <h2 class="h2">Projects</h2>

    <div class="projects__part">
        <h4 class="h4">Primary projects</h4>
        <div class="projects__item">
            <img src="https://hlfppt.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/placeholder.png"  class="projects-item__img">
        </div>

        <div class="projects__item">
            <img src="https://hlfppt.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/placeholder.png"  class="projects-item__img">
        </div>

        <div class="projects__item">
            <img src="https://hlfppt.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/placeholder.png"  class="projects-item__img">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="projects__part">
        <h4 class="h4">Secondary projects</h4>

        <div class="projects__item">
            <img src="https://hlfppt.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/placeholder.png"  class="projects-item__img">
        </div>

        <div class="projects__item">
            <img src="https://hlfppt.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/placeholder.png"  class="projects-item__img">
        </div>

        <div class="projects__item">
            <img src="https://hlfppt.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/placeholder.png"  class="projects-item__img">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>



.projects {
&__part {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(15rem, 1fr));


  /*DESIRED RESPONSIVE EFFECT:
  h4 {
    margin-left: 22rem;
  }
  margin-left: 35rem;
*/  
}


&-item {

    &__img {
        width: 14rem;
        height: 14rem;
        border-radius: 100%/100%;
    }
}


h4 {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
}
```

}

Here's my code : https://codepen.io/maja5252/pen/XPPaBL?editors=1100#0

Again sorry if format of this post is not correct. Still don't know how to split my code to HTML and CSS part :)

Answer (score 1):

A couple issues with your code:

-CSS grid likes to control the size of its columns, and you've got fixed height/width on your images. If you do a DevTools inspection of your code, you'll see your 3rd column is overflowing out of your grid because of this. I changed the height/width to `100%/100%`. If you need square images, fix that issue in Photoshop not CSS.

-Centering the entire grid is pretty simple, all you need to do is add `margin: 0 auto` because it's a block-level element. But, a block level element takes up 100% width of the viewport, so centering a 100% width element won't produce any visible effect. I put the width at 80% to demonstrate how this might look centered, but you could use any non-100% value for this effect.

-I'm also not sure what you're doing with `auto-fit` in your grid. Just use `1fr` and it works really well and the code is clean.

-I also made the whole grid responsive for you - not sure you want to do that, but might as well showcase it.

All the corrected CSS issues together:

```
.projects {
  margin: 0 25px;

  @media (min-width: 450px) {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto; 
  }

  &__part {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 25px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;

    @media (min-width: 450px) and (max-width: 768px) {
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    }

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    }
  }

  &-item {
    &__img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
  }

  h4 {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
  }
}
```

Demo:
https://codepen.io/staypuftman/pen/qMMPwp

Answer (score 0):

I found out, that my H4 headings were disrupting an auto-fit effect, so it worked like auto-fill effect. Code is edited - I pulled headings out of the grid, and it got centered.

to @staypuftman - thanks for your advices - I'll keep them in mind in my future work. Now, when auto-fit works, you can see how responsive it is, without any media query. Again thanks for your effort to help me.

Comment: Interesting, haven't seen `auto-fit` in action but looks cool. Thanks for showing me that in your revised codepen.